# Where can I find a list of system fonts for current and recent OS's?

Tags: website-design, typography

I'm considering using a system font stack for a project so that I can display beautiful typography without the performance hit of webfonts. I'm having difficulties finding a conclusive list of fonts for current and recent operating systems.

Does anyone know of any resources they could point me to?

Related:

- [Implementing system fonts on Booking.com — A lesson learned.](https://booking.design/implementing-system-fonts-on-booking-com-a-lesson-learned-bdc984df627f)
- [System Font Stack | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/system-font-stack/)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/

Answer (score 1):

Most unfortunately you'll have serious trouble finding anything *conclusive*!

http://www.cssfontstack.com/ is a great resource that shows fonts at a glance along with the support on OS and Mac (not every platform of course, but that truly would be a labour of love).

Unfortunately, truly "web-safe" fonts are probably a myth, but Mailchimp probably have the resources to draw up a [decent list](https://templates.mailchimp.com/design/typography/) and they suggest:

- Arial
- Arial Black
- Tahoma
- Trebuchet MS
- Verdana

(Contain your excitement)

With:

- Century Gothic
- Geneva
- Lucida
- Lucida Sans
- Lucida Grande

...as backups. For *serifs*:

- Courier
- Courier New
- Georgia
- Times
- Times New Roman

...plus...

- MS Serif
- New York
- Palatino
- Palatino Linotype

...faced with that list of inspirational typefaces I'd frankly start thinking hard about the performance hit (on modern connections) of a less tedious typeface!

The plus side is that you've reminded me to code some truly outrageous font stacks purely for fun with other designers! I might try:

body {font-family: 'http://www.dafont.com/action-jackson.font', arial) haha

Comment: Thanks. I saw this site, but what it doesn't include is recent OS-specific system font additions like San Francisco, Segoe, and Roboto.